# auth' is not exported from 'firebase' in react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

This is my first time using firebase in react  and I get the error in a userProvider.js file

```
auth' is not exported from 'firebase'
```

while in my firebase.js I do

```
 import "firebase/auth";
 export const auth = firebase.auth();
```

and in my userProvider.js file I import it as

```
import {auth} from 'firebase';
```

I'm a complete beginner in this . I don't know if I'm missing something easy here

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not importing the Firebase SDKs correctly.  Be sure to read the [documentation on using Firebase with module bundlers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#using-module-bundlers).  Starting with v8.0.0, you have to import Firebase SDKs like this:

```
import firebase from "firebase/app"
import "firebase/auth"

const auth = firebase.auth()
```

Do not import from "firebase" directly.

Comment: When I try to export it from another file like ```export const auth = firebase.auth()``` it does not seems to work

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Authentication has a different import structure in version 9 To access the auth object, you should import it from 'firebase/auth' like this;

```
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).